# How can bots detect spam lines or multiple lines of useless text?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to improve my moderation side of my Discord.py bot. I would like users not to send multiple lines of spam or anything considered as "line spam"

If someone were to send a lot of lines to attempt to cause nuisance and just raid a server, how would the bot detect if the message contains too many lines?

In Discord, a simple example of spamming could be sending multiple blank lines with a `.` on the outsides of the blank lines

```
.




.
```

Is there a way to prevent this issue from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to count lines of a given sting.
so that you can use:

```
a = s.count('\n')
```

in this code 'a' counts the lines of attribute 's' and you can limit it like :

```
# if a is bigger than 50 so it is spam , then make it an empty string
if a>50:
    s = ''
```